# SQL add month to a query without calendar table

Tags: sql

I have a pretty simple table here:

---

**Table1**
ID
Date1
Date2
Date3

---

I want to summarize the data by month and ID so the query result comes out like this:

---

**Query Result of table1**
ID
Month
Count of Date1 from the month that's not null
Count of Date2 from the month that's not null
Count of Date3 from the month that's not null

---

I currently have this query below that only pulls one month depending on what @month is specified to:

```
Select ID, @month as [Month]  
Sum((Case When Month(Date1)=@month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date1 Count],   
Sum((Case When Month(Date2)=@month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date2 Count],  
Sum((Case When Month(Date3)=@month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date3 Count],  
From Table1  
Group by ID
```

But I want to pull **all 12 month**, however the database does not have a month table or calendar table, how can I create a query that will include all 12 month for each IDs and get their corresponding monthly counts for Date1, Date2, and Date3?  Btw, a lot of the entries have one of the Dates empty, e.g. Date1 and Date3 = Null whereas Date2 = '01/01/2008'.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you care about the year as well, or do you want to aggregate `01/01/2008` together with `01/01/2012`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only 12 months and that will never change, it's simple enough to use a CTE or subquery to generate the month numbers:

```
;with M as (
  select 1 as month union
  select 2 union
  select 3 union
  select 4 union
  select 5 union
  select 6 union
  select 7 union
  select 8 union
  select 9 union
  select 10 union
  select 11 union
  select 12
)
Select ID, M.Month,
Sum((Case When Month(Date1)=M.Month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date1 Count],   
Sum((Case When Month(Date2)=M.Month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date2 Count],  
Sum((Case When Month(Date3)=M.Month then 1 else 0 END)) as [Date3 Count]  
From M,Table1
Group by ID,M.month
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19ed6b/1

Comment: Thank you very much! this works great! Year is okay I think I gonna use a WHERE and specify year for all three Dates.  But if I want it as part of the result, I'll do the same union group right?

btw, does this have any significant impact on performance compare to using a Month table?

Comment: Are you having performance issues?  If not, I wouldn't be worrying about it for a table set this tiny.